# I getting this error while programming c# :"Thread is not user-suspended; it cannot be resumed." What is it and how can it be fixed?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am on c# working on a multithreaded program for a project I've been working on for school, but ended up getting this issue: "Thread is not user-suspended; it cannot be resumed." How can I fix this issue and what does it mean?
Here's the code where the error occurs.

```
            public static void IndividualThreadTest1()
    {
        individualTestloader = Math.PI;
        individualTestloader++;
        i2.Start();
        while (0 == 0) {
            i5.Suspend();
            individualTestloader = Math.PI;
            individualTestloader++;
            i2.Resume();
        }
    }
    public static void IndividualThreadTest2()
    {
        i1.Suspend();
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader * individualTestloader;
        i3.Start();
        while (0 == 0)
        {
        i1.Suspend();
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader * individualTestloader;
        i3.Resume();

    } }
public static void IndividualThreadTest3()
{
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader * Math.E;
        i4.Start();
        while (0 == 0)
        {
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader * Math.E;
        **i4.Resume();**
} }
    public static void IndividualThreadTest4()
    {
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader - Math.PI;
        i5.Start();
        while (0 == 0)
        {
        individualTestloader = individualTestloader - Math.PI;
        i5.Resume();
    }}
    public static void IndividualThreadTest5()
    {
        individualTestloader = Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E / individualTestloader;
        loopsOfIndividualTest++;
        i1.Resume();
        while (0 == 0)
        {
        individualTestloader = Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E / individualTestloader;
        loopsOfIndividualTest++;
        i1.Resume();
        i5.Suspend();

    }}
```

Each of the functions are on a different thread and each one triggers the next. the first function gets manually started by the rest of the program. What I did here was basically just split up the following equations onto multiple functions which are all on different threads.

```
    loopsOfSharedTest1++;
            double loader = Math.PI;
            loader++;
            loader = loader * loader;
            loader = loader * Math.E;
            loader = loader - Math.PI;
            loader = Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E * Math.E / loader;
```

This is all just a bunch of redundant code that is supposed to stress out the CPU. It runs for 10 seconds and then the threads are stopped(aborted) and I record how many loops the program did. I starred the place where the error is occurring. (It is the i4.Resume at the end of the function "individualThreadTest3".) - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all, I suggest you take a look at the flow of how this all fits together. Ultimately, you cannot `Resume` a thread that has not been `Suspend`ed.

Comment: @DavidG since it is a school project, I think the whole point is to teach the students how the Thread works and that's why the flow is purposely made a little bit "confusing"

Comment: @Ian Yes I understand that, but the code is just a web of thread interdependencies, hence why I suggest rewriting it. I don't understand why anything is being suspended/resumed if the aim is to stress the CPU for 10 seconds, all that could be done with a handful of lines of code.

Comment: @DavidG I see, I think I got your earlier comment wrong. You are not only suggesting that the flow does not make sense but also that the way to produce the stress is incorrect (because of the Suspend and the web threads).

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for your help. I just realized how illogical the question I asked was and fixed it. Being an 8th grader struggling to learn c#, all of your comments and answers really helped. I learned how to "properly" multithread instead of the junk I initially wrote, and just would like to thank you all for giving your time into helping noobs like me.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your help. I just realized how illogical the question I asked was and fixed it. Being an 8th grader struggling to learn c#, all of your comments and answers really helped. I learned how to "properly" multithread instead of the junk I initially wrote, and just would like to thank you all for giving your time into helping noobs like me

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your help. I just realized how illogical the question I asked was and fixed it. Being an 8th grader struggling to learn c#, all of your comments and answers really helped. I learned how to "properly" multithread instead of the junk I initially wrote, and just would like to thank you all for giving your time into helping noobs like me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resume` will throw an exception if the thread is not currently in a suspended state. `i4` is not suspended, so cannot be resumed.

Please note that `Suspend` and `Resume` have been deprecated with .NET 2.0, and are not recommended for use.